# Include Php inside div with Class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to include a php file inside a div which has a specific class. For example in wordpress I have an image wrapped in a class 'generate__sharer__container'. Inside this class I have the image with class 'generate__sharer' i would like to add 'sharer.php' before this.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include "sharer.php";
$myvar = ob_get_clean();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var JSvar = "<?= $myvar ?>";
$(".generate__sharer").before( '**include sharer.php**' );
});
</script>
```

This is as far as I have got. How can I add $myvar before the .generate__sharer

Comment: Have you tried `$(".generate__sharer").before( '<?php include sharer.php; ?>' );`

Comment: Why not just `$(".generate__sharer").before( '<?php echo $myvar; ?>' );`

Comment: Oh thank you will try giving that a go!

Comment: No such luck. I maynot need the The top bit before <script>. But try to get sharer.php to display within .generate__share__container - above . .generate__sharer using js